# chain rule output for matrices after nn.Linear

Tags: python, pytorch

in the case of applying chain rule, for example, we have,

```
x = torch.tensor([1.], requires_grad=True)
def square(x):
  return x**2
def exp(x):
  return torch.exp(x)
z = exp(square(x)) # e^x**2
# derivative is e^(x**2) * 2*x
```

so when we do,

```
z.backward()
x.grad
```

it gives

tensor([5.4366])
which is,
torch.exp(torch.tensor([1.])**2) * 2 * torch.tensor([1.])

but when using matrices,

```
input = torch.randn(3, 3)
a = nn.Linear(3, 3, bias=False)
b = nn.Linear(3, 3, bias=False)
z = b(a(input)).sum()
z.backward()
```

then, we get these matrices,

```
for param in a.parameters():
  print(param.grad)
```

```
tensor([[-0.9843,  0.5633,  0.4002],
        [ 0.7303, -0.4179, -0.2969],
        [ 1.9923, -1.1402, -0.8101]])
```

```
for param in b.parameters():
  print(param.grad)
```

```
tensor([[ 1.8401,  0.5115, -1.3559],
        [ 1.8401,  0.5115, -1.3559],
        [ 1.8401,  0.5115, -1.3559]])
```

how are these two matrices computed?

Comment: Do you know how matrix matrix multiplications work?

Answer (score 0):

after carrying experiment on 2x2 matrix, I was able to obtain derivatives,
PyTorch uses,

```
input @ weight.t()
```

within nn.Linear, so 
derivative with respect to WB[0][0] comes out like,

```
input[0][0]*WA[0][0] + input[0][1]*WA[0][1] + input[1][0]*WA[0][0] + input[1][1]*WA[0][1]
```

derivative with respect to WA[0][0] comes out like,

```
input[0][0]*WB[0][0] + input[0][0]*WB[1][0] + input[1][0]*WB[0][0] + input[1][0]*WB[1][0]
```

which matches with param.grad, for example,

```
input = torch.randn(2, 2)
a = nn.Linear(2, 2, bias=False)
b = nn.Linear(2, 2, bias=False)
z = b(a(input)).sum()
z.backward()
for param in a.parameters():
  print(param.grad)
```

gives

```
tensor([[-0.3518, -0.1145],
        [ 0.0382,  0.0124]])
```

```
for param in b.parameters():
  print(param.grad)
```

gives

```
tensor([[-0.0015,  0.2133],
        [-0.0015,  0.2133]])
```

```
input[0][0]*a.weight[0][0] + input[0][1]*a.weight[0][1] + input[1][0]*a.weight[0][0] + input[1][1]*a.weight[0][1]
```

```
tensor(-0.0015, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```

```
input[0][0]*b.weight[0][0] + input[0][0]*b.weight[1][0] + input[1][0]*b.weight[0][0] + input[1][0]*b.weight[1][0]
```

gives

```
tensor(-0.3518, grad_fn=<AddBackward0>)
```